# Outputting string to binary file doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, I cannot get a simple string to be output to a binary file with python.

Here is my code:

```
strin = bytes(strin, '3DFILE')
dataH = struct.pack('s', strin)
outFile.write(dataH)
```

I'm trying to write a 3D model exporter for a game I am making with blender. can someone please help me out here, or give me an example? I get the error that string is not defined.

Comment: There is no `3DFILE` encoding.

Comment: please provide your imports and full traceback. there is no string in your code, and 3dfile encoding look suspitious

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 strings are sequences of unicode characters. The characters are abstract, and they have no binary representation until you say what encoding should be used.

If you have binary data, you can write it to the binary file (opened with binary mode like `outFile = open(filename, 'wb')` ... `outFile.close()`) without problem. However, writing binary data to the file opened in text mode cannot be done. It was different in Python 2 where strings were actually sequences of bytes and even the open text file object did not care.